# nginx proxy to apache, can't enable keepalive (403)

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

My setup is :

```
upstream http_backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:81;
    keepalive 16;
}

server {
    ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://http_backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }
}
```

But I get a `403` on every page.

If I comment `#proxy_set_header Connection "";` pages are loaded. But accordingly to [nginx docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive), it should be cleared:

> For HTTP, the proxy_http_version directive should be set to “1.1” and the “Connection” header field should be cleared:

Is there anything i must set at Apache side so i can set keeplive between nginx (proxy and ssl offloader) and apache (mpm_event and php-fpm)? `KeepAlive` is set to `On` already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the error was I was setting some headers in the `server` block, outside `location`, so these were cleared by the new `proxy_set_header` directive. I must include them on the `location` block, like:

```
server {
    ...

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://http_backend;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```